# How to add a Password input type in flutter makes the password user input is not visible , just like Android Native EditText 's inputtype:password?

Tags: passwords, flutter

i meet a problem that Flutter 's TextInputType  do not have a password type:

```
/// All possible enum values.

static const List<TextInputType> values = const <TextInputType>[
  text, multiline, number, phone, datetime, emailAddress, url,
];
```

how to make the  password user input not visible? any one has a  good idea ?

Comment: if the answer I provided helped you I would really appreciate it if you can mark it as the answer (simply click the grey checkmark).  If it didn't please let me know why and I would be glad to see if I can help you further.

Comment: all the answers are obsecuring the `TextField` and its working.
but in RTL its not have good experience

Answer (score 374, accepted):

In case you are using the `TextField` widget (or something that derives from this widget), you can use the `obscureText` property and set it to `true`. More details can be found [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextField/obscureText.html).

Additionally, consider adding these properties to prevent input suggestions because they risk revealing at least part of the password input to screen viewers.

```dart
obscureText: true,
enableSuggestions: false,
autocorrect: false,
```

Comment: How to ad option to show the password, like the `eye` appear in some applications

Comment: You could set the `decoration` with a new instance of the `InputDecoration` class and set the `suffixIcon` with a widget that makes sure the `obscureText` property is toggled. This would most likely mean you will have to use a stateful widget containing the `TextField` widget so you can keep track of the state of the `obscureText` property.

Comment: Thanks, can you show some example, I'm new for this

Comment: I believe it's just a matter of toggling `obscureText` in a `StatefulWidget`

Comment: @HasanAYousef `TextFormField(
            obscureText: true,
          ),`

Comment: Please also remember to set `autocorrect` to `false` - you don't want your users to have their passwords saved and auto-suggested by their keyboard

Answer (score 47):

Just add `obscureText: true` in `TextFormField`:

```
 TextFormField(
   obscureText: true,
   decoration: const InputDecoration(
     labelText: 'Password',
   ),
   validator: (String value) {
     if (value.trim().isEmpty) {
       return 'Password is required';
     }
     return null;
   },
 ),
```

Answer (score 17):

There are only two places where we can hide the password.

**1. Using TextFormField**

```
   TextFormField(
                obscureText: true,
                decoration: const InputDecoration(
                  labelText: 'Password',
                ),
              ),
```

**2. Using TextField**

```
              TextField(
                obscureText: true,
                decoration: const InputDecoration(
                  labelText: 'Password',
                ),
              )
```

Answer (score 16):

**Using TextField**

**obscuringCharacter: "*",**

```
 TextField(
        obscureText: true,
        onChanged: (){},
        obscuringCharacter: "*",
        decoration: InputDecoration(
            hintText: "Enter password",
            icon: Icon(Icons.lock,color: kPrimaryColor,),
        ),
      ),
```